# How to kill process (Ubuntu 15.10) when only the mouse barely responds (RAM full, no swap)

Tags: ubuntu, memory, freeze

I'm running several semi-important computations on my PC running Ubuntu 15.10 (Intel i7 6-core, 16 GB RAM, no swap set up)
Not realising that almost all RAM was in use, I opened some tabs in the chromium and now the PC barely responds. When I move the mouse, the cursor barely moves.

I've tried moving the mouse to the cross of the tab and of the program, but no response. I've tried Ctrl + Q, Ctrl + W, Alt + F4, but no responses for over 15 minutes to any of those.

If at all possible, I'd like my computations to remain running and only shut down the browser.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, keyboard responses *did* work, but very, very slowly.
Using Ctrl + Alt + F1 got me into the terminal view, but trying to log in resulted in a 60-second timeout.

Problem was eventually solved by the PC itself, as one of the computations encountered a memory error, got kicked out and released more than enough memory to allow all other computations to continue.

Comment: You need to set up a swap area. Rather than setting up a swap partition, which will mean partition editing, you can set up a swap file using [these straightforward instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). It should be at least as big as your memory, and you should monitor it periodically (`free -h`) to make sure that it does not come anywhere near full.